# Does a window well for an above grade window require a drain?

Tags: basement, windows, drainage

Two window wells will be added to increase the grade on one side of the house. The two windows are currently 3” above ground but soil will be added to improve slope away from house (which is currently lacking).

Comment: Why do you have a well when the window is above grade?

Comment: I will be adding soil to fix current grade resulting in soil being close to base of window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the soil level, they will no longer be "above grade" - the soil level is "the grade" in this case. Increasing the grade puts the windows below grade.

So, probably easier to put drain pipes in before adding more soil. In any case, yes, drain pipes would be advisable.